# Accessing unlinked libc global variable from shell code

Tags: linux, libc, shellcode

Is there any way to find the address of a global variable in libc that hasn't been linked into the executable (therefore not in the got/plt)? I'd like to access the __environ global variable in my shell code.

Web searches have so far only turned up an approach where you first find the offset in the shared library from an entity that is in the plt, and add the offset to the runtime value in the plt to get the runtime address of the desired variable in the shared library. Is there another way that would not depend on the version of the shared library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way that would not depend on the version of the shared library?

No.

The address of `__environ` can be trivially found via many ways other than "first find the offset in the shared library from an entity that is in the plt, and add the offset to the runtime value in the plt to get the runtime address of the desired variable", but that address *will* depend on the exact build of `libc.so.6`, and will vary from version to version (and for the exact same GLIBC version) from distribution to distribution (e.g. different compilers will produce different result).

So what other methods of finding this address exist?

You need two things:

1. The address of the variable within `libc.so.6`, printed by `nm` and `readelf`:

```
nm -D /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 | grep __environ
0000000000202d00 B __environ@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

2. Location of `libc.so.6` itself in a given process, discoverable via e.g. `/proc/$pid/maps`.

```
 grep libc.so.6 /proc/37/maps
7f34d2865000-7f34d2891000 r--p 00000000 08:10 67606                      /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
7f34d2891000-7f34d2a07000 r-xp 0002c000 08:10 67606                      /usr/lib64/libc.so.6
...
```

Above output tells me that `__environ` should be at `0x7f34d2865000+0x0000000000202d00` in process `37`.

```
gdb -q -p 37
...
(gdb) p/a 0x7f34d2865000+0x0000000000202d00
$1 = 0x7f34d2a67d00 <environ>

(gdb) p &__environ
$2 = (char ***) 0x7f34d2a67d00 <environ>
```

QED.

P.S. There are other ways of discovering (1) -- you could read `.dynsym` directly without using `nm`, and (2) -- you could use `dladdr()` within the target process.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I get the reading of .dynsym and reading proc/pid/maps, both can be done in shellcode. But  isn't dladdr also in libc, so you would have to find it's address first?

Comment: @codegen Yes, like I said `dladdr` is usable only from within the target process itself.

Comment: I guess my question is how would you find out the address of dladdr in order to call it from within the target process?